# Error status code 407 does not display in chrome

Tags: java, servlets, error-handling

I am trying error throw servlet program in java. I get all other errors in chrome browser except `error 407(SC_PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED)`

My servlet program is simple and it just throws

```
res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED, "important_parameter needed");
```

and I get `This webpage is not available`
But for all other error codes, I get the messages correctly.

Comment: If you open up the chrome debugger are you seeing a 407 in the traffic?

Comment: please let me know, where exactly can I see the traffic

Comment: right click anywhere on screen, select "Inspect Element", select "Network" in the "Developer Tools" window/pane that pops up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `SC_PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED` because your servlet is not acting as a proxy (I presume). Many HTTP response codes are low-level and are not supposed to be returned by applications.

Comment: in IE I see it in front end. Just not in Chrome.

Comment: Chrome can actually be a bit more rigid when it comes to enforcing HTTP rules (a good thing imo).